# Creating VBnet controlled drop down menu

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need some help once again, I was trying to make myself a drop down menu using aspx and vb.net, it is supposed to show only when certain users are logged in(this works for everything else), the problem is the drop down menu itself, it doesn't display right. It just shows the links in a row.

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="Verwaltung" runat="server" Text="Verwaltung"/>
  <ul>
   <li><asp:LinkButton ID="Verwaltung1" runat="server" Text="Verwaltung" /></li>
   <li><asp:LinkButton ID="Kunden" runat="server" Text="Kunden" /></li>
   <li><asp:LinkButton ID="Kategorien" runat="server" Text="Kategorien" /></li>
 </ul>
```

this is where the drop down menu should be, but it seems it doesn't work this way, and I couldn't find anything helping me, do I have to use a sitemap for a drop down menu?

Comment: have you tried working with [asp.net menu control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: no, gonna try that, but how do I access them with my background code? I need to hide them for non admins

Comment: You can programmatically work with the asp.net menu control from code-behind. This is a powerful, yet lengthy way to deal with the issue based on login-state. If your menu items are relatively static, then you can use some sort of a LoginView and place asp.net menu controls (with links) for the different states respectively.